# If $\lim_{x \to x0} (f(x) * g(x))$ exists, does it mean that $\lim_{x \to x0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x0} g(x)$ also exist?

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x \to x0} (f(x) * g(x))$ exists, does it mean that $\lim_{x \to x0} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to x0} g(x)$ also exist? I know that the opposite side is arithmetic of limits

Comment: No, consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x - x_0}$ and $g(x) =x - x_0 $

Answer (score 1):

No, for a simple example consider one function as x and another as 1/x, then use limit x tends to 0